# Remix issue imputing adresses on GUI

Tags: solidity, remix

I deployed this contract to send token to multiple address at the same time:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract distribution { 

event Transfer(
        address owner,
        address addresses,
        uint _value
        );

mapping(address => uint) balances;

address private owner;

function distributeBlox(address[] addresses, uint256 _value)  {
    for (uint i = 0; i < addresses.length; i++) {
        balances[owner] -= _value;
        balances[addresses[i]] += _value;
        Transfer(owner, addresses[i], _value);
        }
    }
}
```

After the contract deploys I try to input the addresses that I want to send tokens to, usually

"0xd1c13af8D667bBd48F0dd09B61d19659860E656E"

works for inputing and address but since is in an array I was inputting like this:

["0xd1c13af8D667bBd48F0dd09B61d19659860E656E","0xF10257752c3451595e8cE12E 6770fBbbf598E6F6"],5000000.

But it keeps marking me

```
errored: Error encoding arguments: SyntaxError: Unexpected token “ in 
JSON at position 2.
```

I've trying different ways of writing the inputs but nothing seems to work. Any help is more than welcome. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me.

You are using the [Right Double Quotation Mark](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+201D) instead of the [Quotation Mark](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+0022).

It's `"` and not `”`.

You should usually put the integer between quotes too, because at some point, when it's "too big", it will require it too.

Comment: I was making that dumb mistake with the quotations, it works now. Thanks!